# JSDoc with Typescript error for Interace: ERROR: Unable to parse

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I trying to use JSDocs in a react typescript project and I got this error for files that has interfaces

> ERROR: Unable to parse C:******* /file.ts: This experimental syntax
>   requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'flow,
>   typescript' (1:7

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well after doign some research found this project cal [better-docs](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs)
that works over jsdocs and with adding the dependecie and the following configuration on the jsdoc.conf.json fix the issue and allow to work with typescript with nay problems (until now)

```
{
"tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc","closure"]
},
"source": {
    "include": ["src"],
    "includePattern": "\\.(jsx|js|ts|tsx)$",
    "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
},
"plugins": [
    "node_modules/better-docs/typescript"

],
"typescript": {
    "moduleRoot": "test"
},
 "templates": {
  "better-docs": {
      "name": "My React components"
    }
},
"opts": {
    "template": "node_modules/better-docs",
    "destination": "docs",
    "recurse": true,
    "readme": "README.md"
}
```

}